# OnTouchEvent not working on View inside SurfaceView Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, surfaceview, ontouch

I have a surfaceview which draws a joystick view. That view is a custom view which has a ontouchevent and ontouch event is not being called. Why? This is the code...

the surface view:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    public void draw() {
      if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {            
        canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
        //some code
        joystickOnScreen.layout(10, (int)(sh*0.8f), (int)(sh*0.2f), (int)(sh*1f));
        canvas.save();
        joystickOnScreen.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        //some code
        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
      }
    }
}
```

the joystick view:

```
public class Joystick extends View {
    public Joystick(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set the view as clickable?

Comment: @IanMedeiros i already tryed with setFocusable(true); also with setClickable(true), not worked

Comment: Does GameView receive the onTouchEvents ? It can be consuming it?

Comment: @IanMedeiros I'f I implement ontouchevent yes, but I dont want to receive the events there, i want to receive in the joystick view, so I'm not implementing in gameview, i commented that code

Comment: Thats my point. I think that SurfaceView is consuming the MotionEvent and is not broadcasting down to it's children? Can't you notify the Joystick from the SurfaceView?

Comment: @IanMedeiros the code for ontouch event of the surfaceview is commented, doesn't exist. How to notify the joystick? Maybe can you post a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceViews are not [ViewGroups](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup), so, it doesn't behave like normal LinearLayout/RelativeLayout that broadcast their events to their children. Instead, you draw it manually overriding onDraw, or calling a draw method from some outside loop, correct? It's not possible to infer how you are rendering your surface view just by the code you shared, but it seems that you call this draw() method from some kind of controller activity/fragment right?

What you need to do inside the SurfaceView is to do what a ViewGroup usually do for you: find all children elements - *by children I mean the views that you render inside your SurfaceView area* -  and call their onTouchEvent. In your case, it seems that you need just to call Joystick touchEvent.

Here is some example code:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

    //initialization and drawing stuff

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return joystickOnScreen.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but then, how to determine if the joystick has touched? the joystick is in a corner of the screen and the surfaceview is all the screen...